# Invoke selector with scalar argument

Tags: objective-c, ios

I currently use `objc_msgSend` to invoke such selector on collection of object. Is there any better way to do that? Here is my code:

```
@protocol ADelegateProtocol {
   -(void) timeToEventOneDidChange:(NSInterval) event1;
   -(void) timeToEventTwoDidChange:(NSInterval) event1;
}

- (void) delegatesPerformSelector:(SEL) selector withTimeIntervalAsFristParameter:(NSTimeinterval) timeInterval {
    for (id<ADelegateProtocol> delegate in delegates) {
        if([delegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            objc_msgSend(delegate, selector, timeInterval);
        }
    }
}
```

The selector is passed in as a parameter, `timeInterval` is a non-object value.

Note: I don't want to use KVO.

Comment: Please edit the question to add that selector is passed as a parameter. That makes a huge difference.

Comment: I don't think it will really get better without changing the methods you want to call, e.g. `NSInvocation` is more tedious.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something, but this code assumes that any selector passed into this method will take a `timeInterval` as an argument. If you know what the arguments are going to be, why don't you know what the selector is going to be? For instance, a selector `forBar:` might be passed in that takes an `NSTimeInterval` as an arguments, but if I pass in `fooBaz:` that takes a string, `respondsToSelector` will still return true, but you'll send a time interval where a string is expected and cause a crash...

Comment: @Jasarien: I take it that the methods could be like `setFooTimeStamp`, `setBarTimeStamp` etc. But it would be best if Piotr could clarify.

Comment: That's all well and good, but it wouldn't stop the program crashing if any other selector with one argument that a delegate may respond to is passed in. Passing `setFooTimeStamp:` or `setBarTimeStamp:` will be fine, but an `NSObject` or any subclass thereof will respond to, for the sake of argument, `awakeAfterUsingCoder:` which will crash if a timestamp is passed in. What I'm trying to say is this code will work fine under controlled circumstances, but isn't really safe.

Comment: I guess this is just some internal helper where you are reasonably sure this will not happen.

Comment: The other thing I'm getting at is that if you know which methods should be passed, but you just don't know which one or what order at runtime, then you should check for each selector and act accordingly, rather than just ploughing ahead with code like this.

Comment: @Jasarien, I've just updated the code sample which should clarify my use case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are going to use `objc_msgSend()` you **must create a correctly typecast function pointer to do so**.   Relying on varargs to map to non-varargs doesn't work in all cases.

I.e. You'd want:

```
void (*myMessage)(id, SEL, NSTimeInterval) = objc_msgSend;
myMessage(delegate, aSelector, aTimeInterval);
```

(typed into SO -- consider the syntax an approximation. :)

Comment: Interesting. Could you tell me why the code above is better?
I've checked both versions and xcode produce quite similar assembly code.

Comment: Here is the only difference. Your version: `mov -0x14(%ebp),%eax`; `call *%eax`, Original call: `call 0x13dcfe <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>`

Comment: Because the details of the ABI can change over time (barring binary compatibility issues) and because it can vary between different architectures.   You can often get away with relying on varargs being just like non-varargs, but it isn't correct, defensive, or portable.

Comment: +1 I had to search a bit but I've got your point. If anyone is interested here is a nice briefing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573805/using-objc-msgsend-to-call-a-objective-c-function-with-named-arguments/2573949#2573949

Answer (score 1):

What you can use beside `objc_msgSend` (which of course works), is `NSInvocation`. Personally I prefer the `objc_msgSend` way as its the most overhead free way to do this. Its also the more faster way, but this shouldn't matter in a normal App (it does matter in games).

Well, the choice is yours, both ways work and there is nothing bad with `objc_msgSend` or `NSInvocation` (beside that C code looks wrong in an ObjC method).

Answer (score -1):

If delegates is an NSArray: what about using NSArray's `makeObjectsPerformSelector:(SEL)aSelector`.
If you need to pass an object along as a parameter, you can use `makeObjectsPerformSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject`.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, `timeInterval` is a non-object value and therefore can’t be easily passed as `id`.

Comment: You could box it in an object, e.g. using `NSNumber`.

Comment: This will fail because the receiver won't dispatch the NSNumber, the whole method had to be designed to accept NSNumber.