# How do I call methods in a class that I created dynamically with NSClassFromString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, dynamic

The reason I am doing dynamic class loading is because I am creating a single set of files that can be used across multiple similar projects, so doing a #import and then normal instantiation just won't work. Dynamic classes allows me to do this, as long as I can call methods within those classes. Each project has this in the pch with a different "kMediaClassName" name so I can dynamically load different classes based on the project I'm in:

```
#define kMediaClassName @"Movie"
```

Here is the code I am using to get an instance of a class dynamically:

```
Class mediaClass = NSClassFromString(kMediaClassName);
id mediaObject = [[[mediaClass alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Then I try to call a method within that dynamic class:

```
[mediaObject doSomething];
```

When I then type this into Xcode, the compiler shows a warning that the class doesn't have this method, even though it does. I can see it right there in my Movie.h file. What is going on? How do I call a method from a dynamically instantiated class?

And what if I need to pass multiple arguments?

```
[mediaObject loadMedia:oneObject moveThe:YES moveA:NO];
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can declare a protocol, like so:

```
@protocol MONMediaProtocol

/*
  remember: when synthesizing the class, you may want
  to add the protocol to the synthesized class for your sanity
*/

- (BOOL)downloadMediaAtURL:(NSURL *)url toPath:(NSString *)path loadIfSuccessful:(BOOL)loadIfSuccessful;

/* ...the interface continues... */

@end
```

in use:

```
Class mediaClass = NSClassFromString(kMediaClassName);
assert(mediaClass);

id<MONMediaProtocol> mediaObject = [[[mediaClass alloc] init] autorelease];
assert(mediaObject);

NSURL * url = /* expr */;
NSString * path = /* expr */;

BOOL loadIfSuccessful = YES;

BOOL success = [mediaObject downloadMediaAtURL:url toPath:path loadIfSuccessful:loadIfSuccessful];
```

Comment: I was going to recommend using a protocol too, especially since it seems like he has many classes with the same method names.

Comment: After realizing that I need to pass multiple arguments as well as return an object, I think implementing a protocol is most likely the way to go. I'll try to use this.

Answer (score 2):

Well it might be there, but the Compiler doesn't know about it because it assumes that mediaClass is just some Class object, but nothing specific. NSClassFromString() is a runtime function and thus can't give the compiler a hint at compile time about the object.

What you can do:

- Ignore the warning
- Use `[media performSelector:@selector(doSomething)];`

And btw, this is wrong:

```
Class mediaClass; = NSClassFromString(kMediaClassName);
```

it should be:

```
Class mediaClass = NSClassFromString(kMediaClassName);
```

Comment: What if I need to pass multiple arguments to the method? Example: `[mediaObject loadMedia:oneObject moveThe:YES moveA:NO];`

Comment: Then use NSInvocation like Joe Blow already suggested, its your best bet in this case.

Comment: You can always use objective-c runtime functions to accomplish that. Please see my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

An **easier and fancier solution** than NSInvocation :)

```
Class mediaClass = NSClassFromString(kMediaClassName);
if(mediaClass){
    id mediaObject = class_createInstance(mediaClass,0);
    objc_msgSend(mediaObject, @selector(doSomethingWith:andWith:alsoWith:), firstP, secondP,thirdP);
}
```

**Explanation:**

`class_createInstance(mediaClass,0);` does exactly the same as `[[mediaClass alloc] init];`
if you need to autorelease it, just do the usual `[mediaObject autorelease];`

`objc_msgSend()` does exactly the same as `performSelector:` method but `objc_msgSend()` allows you to put as many parameters as you want. So, easier than `NSInvocation` right? BTW, their signature are:

```
id class_createInstance(Class cls, size_t extraBytes)
id objc_msgSend(id theReceiver, SEL theSelector, ...)
```

For more info you can refer the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896533/invoke-selector-with-scalar-argument/4900859#4900859

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. On the iPhone I just needed to make sure I imported the following: #import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/message.h>

Comment: it can do the job, but it's far too dangerous for my taste. see bbum's response in JustSid's link for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As Joe Blow says, NSInvocation will help you here, though NSObject has a couple of shortcut methods that you can use: `-performSelector:`, `-performSelector:withObject:`, and `-performSelector:withObject:withObject:`.