# Calling class method on a Class returned by NSClassFromString()

Tags: objective-c, foundation, class-method

`NSClassFromString(aClassName)` returns a class object of the class named aClassName. Great.

Now how can I call a class method on that class object? For

```
  Class moduleClass = NSClassFromString(aClassName);
```

Xcode won't allow me to either call

```
  AppModule* appModuleClass = moduleClass;
  [appModuleClass classMethod]     // actually that's an object instance...
```

or

```
  [((AppModule)moduleClass) classMethod];     // C-style cast not allowed
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Does calling the selector on `moduleClass` directly not work either - `[moduleClass classMethod]`?

Comment: I only ask as the following causes no problems: `Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"NSString");   NSString *s = [cls stringWithString:@"A string"];`

Comment: @Rich Well, it's Objective-C so of course it works but at compile time it's spilling out a warning..

Comment: I meant compile and runtime. The above produces no warnings, no errors and runs fine. Try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call a class method do so:

```
[NSClassFromString(aClassName) performSelector:@selector(classMethod)];
```

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781046/dynamically-invoke-a-class-method-in-objective-c#answer-1781054) could work:

```
objc_msgSend(NSClassFromString(aClassName), @selector(classMethod));
```

Comment: That's still calling the **instance method**. I need to call the **class method**.  See 1. example in my question.

Comment: Ok, Cheers! Except.. I need to actually call a method with a non-object argument and I'd like to avoid `NSInvocation` - isn't there some way to directly invoke the method..?

Comment: Try this: `objc_msgSend(NSClassFromString(aClassName), @selector(classMethod));`

Comment: Exactly, I've ended up using something along these lines as suggested by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909972/how-do-i-call-methods-in-a-class-that-i-created-dynamically-with-nsclassfromstri?rq=1

Comment: Is it possible to send in parameters into these calls if there are 3-4 parameters?

Comment: @TomHammond Yep, there is. It’s a variadic function, just pass the arguments after the selector. https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1456712-objc_msgsend

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
__typeof([AppModule class]) cls = NSClassFromString(@"aClassName");
if ( [cls respondsToSelector:@selector(classMethod)] ) {
    [cls classMethod];
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.