# How can I perform "SEL fun"

Tags: iphone, ios

if SEL fun is a parameter

how can I go this fun?

for example

```
-(id)init:(SEL)fun
{
  [target fun];
}
```

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

If `fun` expects no arguments, you can do this:

```
[target performSelector:fun];
```

If it expects one object argument, you can do this:

```
[target performSelector:fun withObject:someObject];
```

If it expects two object arguments, you can do this:

```
[target performSelector:fun withObject:someObject withObject:anotherObject];
```

If it expects three or more arguments, or if it expects arguments that are not objects, you have to use `objc_msgSend`, as explained by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573949/77567).

Comment: thank you very much . and do you know how to get this fun as a obj for example           self.targetFun = fun;

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id) init:(NSString*)fun{

[target NSSelectorFromNSString(fun)];

}

- (void) methodCaller{
        [[MyClass alloc] init:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(method1))];
}
```

Comment: thank you very much . and do you know what's the  type of (SEL)fun   for example     I can't do this way       "id targetFun = fun";

Comment: selectors are always represented by counter strings. can you tell the scenario, in which you could get id for selector. fun is always selector of type SEL, and if you want to pass it as an object from 1 method to other, then we are preferring NSString, because Apple has also provided only API for inter-conversion of SEL with NSString.

Answer (score 0):

You can use three mehods for this:

1. Using `performSelector:`  like : `[target performSelector:fun withObject:nil];`
2. Using `detachNewThreadSelector` like:`[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:fun toTarget:target withObject:nil];` but it will work on another thread.
3. Using `NSInvocation` like:

`NSInvocation *inv = [[NSInvocation alloc] init];

[inv setSelector:fun];

[inv invokeWithTarget:target];`

Comment: thank you very much how can I load this fun to another point for example [singleton single].fun = fun;   so that I can move this fun as a obj to another class function

Comment: you can't call the selector using `.` or `[target selector]` these methods. Either you want to call any of the above methods or their variants. If you need to pass the selector to another class then create a `SEL` object there and pass it

Comment: use can take fun as NSString. then can use it as an object, but in both cases you would be require to convert SEL (ivar) to an object. "." operator is used to call getter or setter of property and not function.