# Creating an application on Mac OS X using C++? (without Cocoa)

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, opengl

It seems that in Xcode 4 there is no longer a way to create an application that is not limited to the command line using C or C++. I would like to do so, however Glut seems to be one of the only frameworks available for mac that works with C++ and OpenGL, however gluts features are beginning to stop working on modern Operating Systems. Are there other alternatives that will allow me to use C++ or C for software development on a mac? It does not have to be limited to using xcode or opengl.

Comment: There are some cross-platform GUI toolkits like Qt and GTK that have Quartz or Cocoa backends, but they invariably result in some degree of non-native look-and-feel. You *can* write Cocoa apps using mostly C++ and only a tiny bit of Objective-C.

Comment: How? Are there good places to learn how to do this?

Comment: SDL works on OSX, doesn't it?  Most people use it for games, but there's nothing stopping you from using it for serious work.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, as does [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/)

Comment: I use GLFW + GLEW. Simple and easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but it may not be a very good idea.  The real question is what problem are you trying to solve?

If you just don't like Obj-C, it should be straightforward to write a very thin shim that wraps the calls you care about in C++.

If you are trying to prove a point, you can actually make calls directly into the Obj-C runtime in plain C code.  See this for example: [using objc_msgSend to call a Objective C function with named arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573805/using-objc-msgsend-to-call-a-objective-c-function-with-named-arguments)

If it's something else, please enlighten us so we can better answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

QT is your best bet. It comes with a serious IDE and the libraries are written in a very good & intuitive C++.

QT can be found here: http://qt-project.org/downloads

Comment: For a purist point of view, Qt is not C++. From a practical point of view, Qt is not good C++.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a window, an OpenGL context, and user interfacing, then go the SDL way. Completely written in C, cross platform, and almost object-oriented (most data types are structs, anyways). It's also very memory economic (its core DLL is less than 500KB in size and a windowless program uses less than 1MB of RAM on Linux), unlike the monster that is Qt.

I'd also recommend [LazyFoo's tutorials](http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/) to get started, since they indeed cover the learning from the perspective of a C++ programmer, not a C one.