# objc_msgSend and unions

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I have a problem related to objc_msgSend runtime call, when I have method which returns some union.

I'm calling objc_msgSend function via libffi, and if I have union which is smaller than 16B everything works great, but if the size of union is greater then 16B I'm getting seg fault. 
I tried with objc_msgSend_stret function, and it passes, but I'm getting wrong values for returned union, and I'm not sure with which function are unions called.

Does anyone knows something about union in objective c, how are they handled in objc runtime?

Comment: This is a HUUUUGE problem when you are working with objc_msgSend; basically, ARM (assuming this is for iOS) likes its return values to be placed in registers but some objects just can't fit into a register.  You'll need to call `objc_msgSend_stret` instead with the address you want your union to be stuffed into.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSend_stret

Comment: What platform is this for?  iOS?

Answer (score 6):

This is a HUUUUGE problem when you are working with `objc_msgSend`; basically, most ABIs like their return values to be placed in registers (here are all the gory details for the brave and curious: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/000-Introduction/introduction.html) but some objects just can't fit into a register (which is why union sizes <= 16 worked for you properly). You'll need to call `objc_msgSend_stret` instead with the address you want your union to be stuffed into.

Another good reference: http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/10/30/objc_explain_objc_msgSend_stret.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSend_stret

Solution:  Instead of casting and calling `objc_msgSend`, cast and call `objc_msgSend_stret`.

```
void objc_msgSend_stret(void * stretAddr, id theReceiver, SEL theSelector,  ...)
```

so your cast would be (like [using objc_msgSend to call a Objective C function with named arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573805/using-objc-msgsend-to-call-a-objective-c-function-with-named-arguments)):

```
union myUnion {
    int a, b;
    char c;
    double d;
};

// For objc_msgSend_stret
void (*objc_msgSend_stretTyped)(union myUnion* stretAddr, id self, SEL _cmd, float bar) = (void*)objc_msgSend_stret;

union myUnion u;
float pi = 4;

objc_msgSend_stretTyped(&u, obj, sel_getUID(sel), pi);
```

### EDIT -- Skip all above code

Here is how I managed to get objc_msgSend_stret working:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/objc.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

union myUnion {
    int myArray[32];
    int a,b,c,d;
};

void doStuff(id obj, SEL sel);

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    doStuff(self, @selector(doStuff:));
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (union myUnion) doStuff: (int)myInt {
    NSLog(@"Pi equals %d", myInt);
    union myUnion u;
    for(int i=0; i<32; i++) {
        u.myArray[i] = i*i*i*i-1;
    }
    return u;
}

@end

void doStuff(id obj, SEL sel) {
    int pi = 4;
    NSLog(@"myUnion is: %luB", sizeof(union myUnion));
    NSLog(@"Sizeof(int) = %luB ... Sizeof(char) = %lub ... sizeof(double) = %luB", sizeof(int), sizeof(char), sizeof(double));

    union myUnion u = ((union myUnion(*)(id, SEL, int))objc_msgSend_stret)(obj, sel, pi);
    NSLog(@"Union u = {%d, %d, %d, %d}", u.myArray[30], u.myArray[29], u.myArray[28], u.myArray[27]);
}
```

Comment: Small structs returned in registers is generally true, except for PPC, according to Greg Parker http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/10/30/objc_explain_objc_msgSend_stret.html. The full details are in Apple's ABI Reference.

Comment: @Josh, Ah!! I was trying to find that article (I remembered the hamster!) ... I knew I was forgetting something important!

Comment: Your function pointer cast for objc_msgSend_stretTyped() is wrong. You need to cast it to a function pointer that returns the struct. On some ABIs, a function that returns a struct is not identical to a function that returns void with a struct pointer parameter.

Comment: tnx you guys on your answers...I know story about ABI-s, and objc_msgSend/objc_msgSend_stret calls and that they not always save results in registers, but my problem actually was related to libffi and handling unions in libffi. It seems that we need to specify size of FFI_TYPE_STRUCT type, to objc_msgSend works OK with libffi :)

Comment: But still I have problems :(. If you try to run method which returns union which is larger then 16B, xcode still calling success objc_msgSend function, and crashes if we try to call objc_msgSend_stret function, even if we have union of size, for example 300B....but with libffi it's a little bit different situation.

Comment: @Greg, is the updated cast correct?  I wasn't aware that there was a difference between returning void* and someStruct*.  user232343: I'm going to run a few tests and see if I can get the same errors that you are getting...

Comment: @user232343, I've updated my code with actual working code now haha.

Comment: @GeorgeMitchell it is working now. For some reason (in my case) if we run program compiled from xcode, every time objc_msgSend function is called, but when you make call with libffi, both objc_msgSend and objc_msgSend_stret are called (depending on return size). So if you call this functions with libffi, you need to use union_type.type = FFI_TYPE_STRUCT, and provide union_type.size = actualSize, where actual size is sizeof every struct in union, and union itself, otherwise it won't work.