# Is it safe to use objc_msgSend in the follow situation?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I have an object and a selector to invoke on said object. The selector will take one of 4  forms (modelled to be similar to the target-action pattern):

`-(void)selectorWithZeroArguments;
 -(void)selectorWithObject:(id)object;
 -(void)selectorWithObject:(id)object dictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
 -(void)selectorWithObject:(id)object dictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict string:(NSString *)string;`

```
Currently I have a `switch` as follows:

```
switch ([[object methodSignatureForSelector:selector] numberOfArguments]) {
    case 2:
        objc_msgSend(object, selector);
        break;

    case 3:
        objc_msgSend(object, selector, otherObject);
        break;

    case 4:
        objc_msgSend(object, selector, otherObject, dictionary);
        break;

    case 5:
        objc_msgSend(object, selector, otherObject, dictionary, string);
        break;
}
```

```

Would it be safe to remove the switch statement and only use `objc_msgSend(object, selector, otherObject, dictionary, string)`? My testing suggests that sending additional arguments to `objc_msgSend` is harmless and I can find no documentation to support or refute this.

Also, is there a better way to approach this problem? I know that I could use `NSInvocation` but that seems vastly more cumbersome for no gains.

Comment: Have a look at [Messaging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html) in the Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide: *"The pointer that methodForSelector: returns must be carefully cast to the proper function type.  …"* - Compare also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2573949/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the link. But I don't think the specific point you make is relevant. I'm not using the return value to get a function pointer. I'm using it to determine how many arguments the method takes.

Comment: Why the down vote? How can I improve the question?

Comment: My point is that objc_msgSend() is not meant to be called directly. I think it is quite well explained in the second link.

Comment: The down vote because this is a horrendous solution. Consider to developer coming along behind you (it might even be you next year), with they say: WTF? I would. There is nothing better than clear concise simple code.

Comment: @Zaph: Is that really a reason to downvote? The question is clear and Benedict has done some testing before posting it, so this is better than many, many other questions. The *approach* might be bad, but the *question* isn't (in my opinion).

Comment: @Martin You have a good point. I just see so much bad code. So few developers taking the time to study and learn the principles of writing good code. I am jaded by all the horrible code, the cute code.

Answer (score 2):

So with a bit more searching on developer.apple.com and some help from the Objective-C mailing list I've concluded that it is not sensible to call `objc_msgSend` with additional arguments. However it is fine to use `objc_msgSend` providing it is cast to the correct function prototype. An example from above:

```
objc_msgSend(object, selector, otherObject)
```

should be cast as:

```
((void(*)(id, SEL, id))objc_msgSend)(object, selector, otherObject);
```

This cast will allow the compiler to ensure that the stack frames are correctly constructed.

The code for `NSInvocation` version is comparatively less cumbersome than the casted version so I'll probably uses that. I'm also going to do some benchmarks to satisfy my curiosity.

Documentation:

- [Objective-C Runtime Reference: Sending Messages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW49)
- [64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa Touch: Dispatch Objective-C Messages Using the Method Function’s Prototype](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html)