# Objective C: Two implicit parameters passed to every method called by an object

Tags: objective-c-2.0

What are the two implicit parameters passed to every method by an object in Objective-c? Is it _cmd and id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a good question,
the short answer is:
yes, two parameters are being implicitly passed. *self* of type *id*, and *_cmd* of type *SEL*.

to better understand it, here is what happens behind the method call.

```
@interface Item:NSObject
-(void)dummyMethod;
@end
@implementation Item
-(void)dummyMethod{
     NSLog(@"dummyPrint");
}
@end
```

a normal method call would be like:

```
Item* objectOne = [[Item alloc]init;
[objectOne dummyMethod];
```

that call gets translated/complied to:

```
objc_msgSend(objectOne,@selector(dummyMethod)); //since the dummy method takes no parameters and returns void
```

to try it/use it your self.

1. `#import<objc/message.h` 

2. cast the `objc_msgSend` method to an appropriate function pointer type before being used, like that.

```
void (*objc_msgSendPointer)(id self, SEL _cmd) = (void*)objc_msgSend;
objc_msgSendPointer(one, @selector(dummyMethod));
```

here is the function declaration

```
 id objc_msgSend(id self, SEL op, ...);
```

take a look at this documentation for further info..
[objc_msgSend](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1456712-objc_msgsend?language=objc).

take a look also at this topic [using objc_msgSend to call a Objective C function with named arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573805/using-objc-msgsend-to-call-a-objective-c-function-with-named-arguments)
 for more info regarding other methods, specially Ken's answer.

I hope that was helpful!